# SwiftUI Initialzier requires String conform to Identifiable

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am attempting writing some SwiftUI code for the very first time and am running into an issue while trying to make a simple table view. In this code `teams` is an array of `String`, but the `List` is giving me the following error:

> Initializer 'init(_:rowContent:)' requires that 'String' conform to 'Identifiable'

```
var body: some View {
    let teams = getTeams()
    Text("Hello there")
    List(teams) { team in
        
    }
}
```

Anyone have an idea what it means?

Answer (score 42):

The argument of `List` is required to be unique, that's the purpose of the `Identifiable` protocol

You can do

```
List(teams, id: \.self) { team in
```

but then **you** are responsible to ensure that the strings are unique. If not you will get unexpected behavior.

Better is to use a custom struct with an unique `id` conforming to `Identifiable` for example

```
struct Team: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
}
```

Then you can use your syntax as-is.

Comment: I'm worried that suggesting this to someone new to SwiftUI will lead to immediate foot-gunning, akin to teaching new Swift devs about `!`.

Comment: conforming to **Identifiable**. was the key here

Answer (score 28):

The Apple preferred way to do this is to add a String extension:

```
extension String: Identifiable {
    public typealias ID = Int
    public var id: Int {
        return hash
    }
}
```

See this code sample for reference:
https://github.com/apple/cloudkit-sample-queries/blob/main/Queries/ContentView.swift

Comment: Great find @Josh!
I'm actually surprised why they didn't just go with returning `self` for `id`.

Comment: This is a really bad example from Apple. This fundamentally does not work. It will break your UI any time your List contains two strings with the same value. They will have the same identity, and thus be indistinguishable, which is a problem because they obviously need to be distinguishable if they're going to appear in different positions of the list.

Comment: Alexander is correct. However, depending on your exact use case, what you could do is declare a typealias such as `typealias UniqueID = String` and make `teams` an array of that, then create the above extension for `UniqueID: Identifiable`. You just have to ensure you only do this if the strings you use are actually always going to be unique.

Comment: The compiler would still treat any `String` in the scope as conforming to `Identifiable` even if you used a `typealias` like that.

Just because a piece of Apple's example code does something doesn't mean it's the generally preferred way to do it. In this case this is just an example for implementing CloudKit, so they cut some corners to simplify things with this String extension.

Comment: **Don't do this**. If you are **sure** your strings are all unique, you can use the string itself as an identifier. But **even** if all strings are guaranteed to be unique, their hashes are **not** guaranteed to be unique!

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming that `getTeams()` returns a `[String]` (a.k.a. an `Array<String>`).

The issue, as the error suggests, are the strings aren't identifiable. But not just in the "they don't conform to the `Identifiable` protocol" sense, but in the broader sense: if two strings are `"foo"`, one is indistinguishable from the other; they're identical.

This is unacceptable for a `List` view. Imagine you had a list that contains `"foo"` entries, and the users dragged to rearrange one of them. How would `List` be able to tell them apart, to know which of the two should move?

To get around this, you need to use an alternate source of identity to allow the `List` to distinguish all of its entries.

You should watch the ["Demystify SwiftUI" talk from this year's WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/). It goes into lots of detail on exactly this topic.

Answer (score 6):

If your trying to go over a 'List' of items of type 'Struct'
Change the Struct to use 'Identifiable':

my Struct:

```
 struct Post : Identifiable{
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
}
```

my List :

```
let posts = [
    Post( title: "hellow"),
    Post( title: "I am"),
    Post( title: "doing"),
    Post( title: "nothing")
]
```

then you can go over your List:

```
List(posts){post in
   Text(post.title
}
```

Comment: What to do when `Cannot convert value of type 'UUID' to specified type 'ObjectIdentifier'`

Comment: Remove the type `ObjectIdentifier` in your intialization, i.e. use `let id = UUID()` not `let id: ObjectIdentifier = UUID()`.